# How to execute powershell script from jenkins by passing parameters

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a powershell script in my Github. i am trying to execute that via Jenkins. Here is a part of the script :-

```html
param (
+    [string]$fileDir = "%WORKSPACE%\src\Project\***",
 [string]$packagingDir = "%WORKSPACE%\src\packageTemp", 
 [string]$staticFilesToDeploy = "%WORKSPACE%\src\****"
  )
```

Now i am using a simple batch execution within Jenkins Job to run  this script. I am trying to run it as

```html
powershell -noexit "& ""%WORKSPACE%\src\***.ps1"""
```

But when Jenkins actually executes this powershell script its unable to replace %workspace% within the script and fails as it cannot find that. How do i make jenkins to replace that within the script when it executes it actually

Comment: I'm not into Jenkins, but shouldn't `%WORKSPACE%` rather be [$WORKSPACE](https://learn.akamai.com/en-us/webhelp/cloudtest/touchtest-jenkins-ci-for-ios-tutorial/GUID-9BD3DE22-74D3-44AA-B2C5-158C4959D610.html)? The `%` characters are used in Windows batch commands.

Comment: Oh my bad, but even replacing it with $WORKSPACE, the powershell script is unable to extract exact value for it correctly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved by passing arguments for the powershell script through jenkins :-

```html
powershell.exe -file "%WORKSPACE%\src\***.ps1" -fileDir "%WORKSPACE%\src\Project\***" -packagingDir "%WORKSPACE%\src\packageTemp" -staticFilesToDeploy "%WORKSPACE%\src\****"
```

This force sets the values for the params within the script at run time and at the same time can be issued via jenkins to be able to make use of its environment variables.