# Retrieve value from powershell script in jenkins file

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I try to retrieve a string from a powershell script and use it in Jenkins file, in order to change the displayed version in SonarQube.

I started to implement functionality for taking the project version from `package.json`. Basically I give a `Workspace` directory as param and I ask for the full path if he finds a `package.json` in `Workspace` itself or in child folders. If the file is found, parse it and return version:

*updateDisplayedVersionInSonar.ps1*

```
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
  [string]$Workspace
)
try{

    $packageFullPath = ""
    $pcgVersion = ""

    Get-ChildItem -Path ${Workspace} -Filter package.json
     -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | % {$packageFullPath = $_.FullName}
    try { 

      Test-Path $packageFullPath -PathType leaf

      $json = Get-Content $packageFullPath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

      if($json.PSobject.Properties.Name -contains "version"){       
        $pcgVersion =  $json.version
      }
      else{
        $pcgVersion = "unknown"
      }

      Write-Output $pcgVersion          
  }
  catch {
    Write-Output "There is no package.json file!"
  }
}
catch{
  $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
  write-host "An error has occured: ${ErrorMessage}"
  exit 1
}
```

Now I want to use the version returned from ps script in a Jenkins file:

```
stage('SonarQube Frontend') {
environment {
    sonarqubeScannerHome = tool name: 'SonarQube Scanner', type: hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation'
    sonarQubeId = 'SonarQubeServer'
    sonarProjectName = "\"SPACE ${REPOSITORY_NAME}\""
    sonarProjectKey = "${REPOSITORY_NAME}"
    testsPaths = 'app/myProject-ui/webapp/TEST/unit/utils'
    testExecutionReportPaths = 'app/myProject-ui/reports/sonar/TESTS-qunit.xml'
    javascriptLcovReportPaths = 'app/myProject-ui/reports/coverage/lcov.info'
}
steps {

    withSonarQubeEnv(env.sonarQubeId) {     
        withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: sonarQubeId, usernameVariable: 'SONAR_USER', passwordVariable: 'SONAR_PASSWORD']]) {   
            script{
                sonarProperties =  " -Dsonar.projectName=${env.sonarProjectName}" +
                    " -Dsonar.projectKey=${env.sonarProjectKey}" +   
                    " -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_USER}" +
                    " -Dsonar.password=${SONAR_PASSWORD}" +
                    " -Dsonar.sources=./" +  
                    " -Dsonar.exclusions=**/*.java"
                //some other conditions

                //this line will be executed and i will see in Jenkins Console output the version found in package.json
                powershell "powershell -File C:/Automation/updateDisplayedVersionInSonar.ps1 -Workspace '${env.WORKSPACE}/app'"

                //I try to make it as a variable, but it will print "echo version here - null -" :(
                pcgVersion = powershell "powershell -File C:/Automation/updateDisplayedVersionInSonar.ps1 -Workspace '${env.WORKSPACE}/app'" 
                echo "echo version here - ${pcgVersion} -"

                //I want to use it here in order to be displayed the correct version of the app in Sonar
                sonarProperties = sonarProperties + " -Dsonar.projectVersion= ${pcgVersion}" 
            }

        bat "${env.sonarqubeScannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner" + " -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_HOST_URL}" + sonarProperties
        }   

    } 
}
} //end of SonarQube Frontend stage
```

I tried the solution from [How to execute powershell script from jenkins by passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874974/how-to-execute-powershell-script-from-jenkins-by-passing-parameters) but without any result.

I tried also to do this way:

```
version = powershell(returnStdout: true, script:'powershell -File C:/SCP/Automation/updateDisplayedVersionInSonar.ps1 -Workspace "${env.WORKSPACE}"')


version = powershell(returnStdout: true, script:'C:/SCP/Automation/updateDisplayedVersionInSonar.ps1 -Workspace "${env.WORKSPACE}"')
```

I found quite a lot of examples of how to use Jenkins variable in Powershell, but not vice versa :(

What I am doing wrong? It is possible to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the error that you see? Try replacing single quotes with double quotes and removing `env` before `WORKSPACE` as in `version = powershell(returnStdout: true, script:"C:/SCP/Automation/updateDisplayedVersionInSonar.ps1 -Workspace $WORKSPACE")`.

Comment: You could use build-in jenkins utils to read a json file https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace
`def props = readJSON file: 'app/package.json' props['version']`
to get the version

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Jenkins Pipeline Utility](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) instead.

```
def getPackageVersion() {
  def package = readJSON file: '${env.WORKSPACE}/app/package.json'
  echo package.version
  return package.version
}
```

Then you should be able to access it like this.

```
def pcgVersion = getPackageVersion()
```

Comment: Hmm, i didn't think at doing this in groovy directly, but i'll try..